# Is more requested MATLAB or Python in companies (for engineers)?

Tags: matlab

My question is not exactly on MATLAB vs Python in terms of features (about which there are plenty of topics yet).

It's a specific question for engineers who have a certain experience with some companies: have you been requested to work more with MATLAB or Python?

I'm referring to use them to write code for math purposes, plotting graphics, fourier transform computations, signal processing etc

How many times have you been requested to work with MATLAB and how many times with Python?

Answer (score 1):

**If your employer wants you to do things in MATLAB, then do them in MATLAB.**

Learning python on your spare time and evangelizing if it works for you at work is another matter. At some point you might call the shot and actually change to python.

Notice, I am not discussing merits for each platform.

The reason why people might be asking you to do work on MATLAB is maybe because there is a lot of experience/code already, and it is difficult to make the transition.